# Python multiprocessing, ThreadPool. ThreadPool останавливается в конце

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing, pool

Я написал скрипт, который "парсит" все домены из файла. После запуска все парсится быстро (как и должно быть) до конца. В конце он останавливается, когда остается несколько доменов. Иногда, парсинг последних нескольких доменов занимает много времени.

Я не могу понять, в чем проблема. Разницы нет, **1000** доменов или **10 000** доменов. Кто сталкивался с такой ситуацией? Подскажите, как это вылечить.

**Код:**

```
import re
import sys
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

pool = 100

with open("Rules.json") as file:

    REGEX = json.loads(file.read())

ua = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'}

def Domain_checker(domain):

    try:

        r = requests.get("http://" + domain, verify=False, headers=ua)
        r.encoding = "utf-8"

        for company in REGEX.keys():

            for type in REGEX[company]:

                check_entry = 0

                for ph_regex in REGEX[company][type]:

                    if bool(re.search(ph_regex, r.text)) is True:

                        check_entry += 1

                        if check_entry == len(REGEX[company][type]):

                            title = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

                            Found_domain = "\nCompany: {0}\nRule: {1}\nURL: {2}\nTitle: {3}\n".format(company, type, r.url, title.title.text)
                            print(Found_domain)

                            with open("/tmp/__FOUND_DOMAINS__.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as file:

                                file.write(Found_domain)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
        pass
    except UnicodeError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError:
        pass
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return domain


if __name__ == '__main__':


    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as file:

        Domains = file.read().split()

    pool = 100
    print("Pool = ", pool)

    results = ThreadPool(pool).imap_unordered(Domain_checker, Domains)

    string_num = 0

    for result in results:

        print("{0} => {1}".format(string_num, result))

        string_num += 1


    with open("/tmp/__FOUND_DOMAINS__.txt", encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as found_domains:

        found_domains = found_domains.read()

    print("{0}\n{1}".format("#" * 40, found_domains))
```

Comment: Может дело в парсере и сервисах, которые он использует

Comment: Добавил полный код

Comment: вместо пассов выведи ошибки на экран - они бывают полезны. возможно там просто ждет таймаут на битую ссылку

Comment: eri. Да, проблема решена после установки timeout=10 для requests. "таймаут на битую ссылку". СПАСИБО!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get("http://" + domain, headers=ua, verify=False, timeout=10)
```

Проблема решена после установки `timeout` благодаря комментарию от [@eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1131882/#comment1957290_1131882).